# JqGrid don'i reload after click on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, reload

I work with jqGrid on my project and I have a problem that can not seem to solve even after reading the forums on the same subject.

I would reload the grid when a user clicks a button after selecting a date. I want the data recharge correspodent to choose the date.

I use the following code:

```
var loadfacture  = false;

    $('#btn-facture').click(function(){     

        if(!loadfacture){           

            $("#factures").jqGrid({
                url:'loadfactureencours.json',
                datatype: "json",           
                autowidth: true,
                height:250,
                colNames:['#','Numero','Date', 'Client','Serveur','Prix Total','Avance','Regler','Notes'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'idfac',index:'idfac', width:45,align:"center"},
                    {name:'numfac',index:'numfac', width:80,align:"center"},
                    {name:'datefac',index:'datefac', width:150,align:"center"},
                    {name:'client',index:'client', width:145,align:"center"},
                    {name:'utilisateur',index:'utilisateur', width:125,align:"center"},                     
                    {name:'montant',index:'montant', width:70,align:"center"},
                    {name:'avance',index:'avance', width:60,align:"center"},
                    {name:'regler',index:'regler', width:50,align:"center"},
                    {name:'description',index:'description', width:150, sortable:false}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                rowTotal: 2000,
                rowList : [10,20,30,40,50,60],
                loadonce:true,
                mtype: "GET",
                postData: {
                    day: function () {                      
                        return $('#daySelect').val();
                    }
                },
                rownumbers: false,
                rownumWidth: 40,
                gridview: true,
                pager: '#paging',
                sortname: 'idfac',  
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "",
                ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){
                    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowid);
                    console.log(rowData);
                    window.location = "ecrancommandebar.html?num="+rowData.numfac;
                }
            });

            $("#factures").jqGrid('navGrid','#paging',{del:false,add:false,edit:false});
            loadfacture  = true;


        }else{          

            var grid = $("#factures");
                   grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);

        }

    });
```

I built this piece of code by reading the forum on the same subject but the grid load the first time then when I click on the button after changing the date nothing happens.

What is wrong with you? Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `loadonce:true` option which changes `datatype` from initial `"json"` to `"local"` after the first loading of the data from the server. It allows to support *local* sorting, paging and filtering of data. So you should understand that `grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);` will just reload the data *from previously saved previous response*. So no reloading from the server will take place till you reset the value of `datatype` parameter to `"json"`. In other words you should rewrite `else` part to about the following

```
...
} else {          
    $("#factures").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"})
        .trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true, page: 1}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
}else{          
   var grid = $("#factures");
   $.ajax({
      url: "loadfactureencours.json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
      },
      error: function(){}
   });

}
```